# это неполадки с opengl или нет?

Tags: linux, opengl, opengles

проблема с отображением текста. такой глюк и в sdl2 и в sfml. кто нибудь знает что это может быть? в коде вроде всё нормально. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я уменьшил кнопки, ну прямоугольники и проблема пропала. но в чем проблема не пойму. код вроде прямоугольников нормальный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слишком мало входящих данных чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос. Определите сначала, как часто и при каких обстоятельствах происходит этот баг, влияет ли он только на текст или что-то ещё.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf проблемы наблюдались только с текстом. раньше вроде всё нормально было. но я не знаю что поменял. вроде ничего. но когда появились ошибки. пришлось в некоторых местах вместо new struct ... делать calloc, чтобы всем указателям сразу NULL присваивался.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf  смотри, я обнову сделал здесь.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf а нет. это было случайно. то есть иногда нет линий, иногда есть.

Comment: я не спец в opengl. свою игрушку на досуге предпочитаю кодить на love2d, там opengl напрямую не используется, по этому я вряд ли смогу помочь, но думаю, если выложите код, кто-нибудь поможет. если считаете что проблема не в коде, попробуйте может быть поменять драйвер с проприетарного на свободный ради эксперимента.